# Flutter GoRouter with Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, gorouter

I am using the [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/install) and Firebase Auth for my web application but can not properly set it up. I tried this:

```
class AuthService {
  static final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static User? get currentUser => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  static bool isLoggedIn() {
    return _firebaseAuth.currentUser != null;
  }
  ...
```

With my `router`:

```
  redirect: (context, state) {
    final String destination = state.location;

    final bool isOnStartView = destination == '/start';
    final bool isOnEmailFlow = state.subloc.contains('/email');

    if (!isOnStartView && !isOnEmailFlow && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return '/start';
    }

    return null;
  },
```

However this is not working properly as `isLoggedIn` is always return `false` even if there a is a user logged in. I searched for this topic and found that I probably use some sort of `Stream` or `Notifier` with `onAuthStateChange` but I didn't find anything on how to implement a proper **FirebaseAuthentication Flow in combination with GoRouter**.

How would I do that?

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What state management you're using?? And maybe the code, where you're trying to navigate might help everyone understand it better. There are a few things I can think of that might have gone wrong. But with this little amount of info, I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: @HippoFish I m using `provider`. But for authentication I don't store any extra information. I only use the code above. Anything specific that would help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use riverpod or provider to listen changes
here is code sample

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:testproject/Home%20Screen/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:testproject/Model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:testproject/Providers/UserProvider/user_data_provider.dart';
import 'package:testproject/Screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:testproject/Screens/sign_up.dart';
import 'package:testproject/Service/auth_service.dart';

import '../Providers/Satates/user_states.dart';
import '../Providers/UserProvider/user_state_provider.dart';

class MyRoutes extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Ref ref;
  MyRoutes(this.ref) {
    ref.listen<LoginState>(
        userStateprovider, (previous, next) => notifyListeners());
  }

  List<GoRoute> get _routes => [
        GoRoute(
          name: "Login",
          path: "/login",
          builder: (context, state) => SigninPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "Home",
          path: "/home",
          builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "Signup",
          path: "/signup",
          builder: (context, state) => const SignUpScreen(),
        ),
      ];

  String? _redirectLogic(GoRouterState state) {
    final loginState = ref.read(userStateprovider);
    final user = ref.read(userProvider.state);
    if (loginState is LoginStateInitial && auth.currentUser != null) {
      log("message");
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
        user.state = UserModel(
            email: auth.currentUser!.email!, userid: auth.currentUser!.uid);
        ref.read(userStateprovider.notifier).newstate = LoginStateSuccess(
            UserModel(
                email: auth.currentUser!.email!,
                userid: auth.currentUser!.uid));
      });
    }
    log(state.location);
    log(auth.currentUser.toString());
    final areWeLoggingIn = state.location == '/home';
    log(areWeLoggingIn.toString());
    if (areWeLoggingIn) {
      return loginState is LoginStateSuccess ? null : "/login";
    }

    return null;
  }
}

final routeProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final routeRef = MyRoutes(ref);
  return GoRouter(
      urlPathStrategy: UrlPathStrategy.path,
      initialLocation: "/login",
      refreshListenable: routeRef,
      redirect: routeRef._redirectLogic,
      routes: routeRef._routes);
});
```

Comment: only checking `auth.currentUser!.uid` is not working for me. Is this working for you both for refresh the page and with hot reload? (multiple times)

Comment: yes it working in all scenarios

Answer (score -2):

You can do this

```dart
class AuthService {
  static final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static User? get currentUser => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  static bool? _isLoggedIn = null;


  static bool isLoggedIn() {
    if(_isLoggedIn == null) {
       FirebaseAuth.instance
          .authStateChanges()
          .listen((User? user) {
             _isLoggedIn = user?.uid != null;
           });
       _isLoggedIn = _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid != null;
       return _isLoggedIn ?? false;
    }
    else {
       return _isLoggedIn ?? false;
    }
  ...
```

Comment: not working for me. Same result. Log out on refresh. Sometimes it works on the first reload but trying it multiple times always fails :(

Comment: Do you have `  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
`?

Comment: This has a side effect where every time you call `isLoggedIn()` a new listener is created on `authStateChanges`, which can lead to memory problems.